# Should I use blue light exclusively in the seedling stage, or red/blue/yellow light combined?

Tags: plant-care

I bought this LED lamp for plants that switches either from entirely blue light, entirely red light, entirely yellow light, red and blue light together, or all three together.

I've read that blue light is important at the seedling stage, and red light is better towards the reproductive stage. I'm not sure what yellow light is for.

Is it better to exclusively use the blue light mode on the seedlings or should I use the mode where all 3 lights are combined?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this topic but I've done some experiments on this topic with grass seeds in the past.

Plants are able to "absorb" light in the blue and red spectrum. So I’d say go with blue and red.

Here are some pictures of the grass 4 days after starting the experiment:

With red+blue light:
[image]

With natural light:
[image]